# How to use LtiAdvantage nuget package for LTI1.3 feature under Net Framework 4.8 in VS2019?

Tags: c#, lti

How to use LtiAdvantage nuget package for LTI1.3 feature under Net Framework 4.8 in VS2019?

I tried install LtiAdvantage nuget package for LTI1.3 feature under Net Framework 4.8 in VS2019.
But, I got this "Unable to parse version value '0.2.0-alpha.0' from 'packages.config'.". So,how to use LtiAdvantage nuget package for LTI1.3 feature under Net Framework 4.8 in VS2019?